# How to change the value of an integer in flutter

Tags: flutter

What i'm trying to do is, whenever on of those boxes is press, to get to another screen and change the value of foodindex.

```
SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              FractionallySizedBox(
                widthFactor: 0.95, // 95% of the screen width
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Recipes()),
                    );
                    foodindex = 1;
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
                      const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                      const Text('Chicken Alfredo',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, ),),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I have made my research and what i have done is the following:

```
void change(int n) {
    setState(() {
      foodindex += 1;
    });
}
```

However, setState is underlined. and it's telling me that the function is not definded.
So, how do i fix this?

Comment: `setState` are available inside `StatefullWidget` .  make sure you put it between curly brackets of state class

Answer (score 0):

`setState` must be called inside a State's subclass, which is hold your widget's states.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget { // Use StatefulWidget if your widget have states
  const YourWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  @override                               //
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    // Your can call setState here
    return /** UI code **/                //
  }                                       //
}
```